# Transform Limit definition of $e$

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit definition of $e$ can be written as:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} {\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x} . $$

This is equal to another similar form:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} {(1 + x)^{\frac{1}{x}}} . $$

I am wondering how to prove these 2 forms are equivalent, any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Swap out $x$ for $\frac1x$

Comment: $\frac{1}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: The second one should be $\lim_{x\to 0+},$ the right limit to $0.$ While it is true the left limit is also equal to $e,$ it doesn’t follow from the first limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  We can start with $$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x}$$ and use the substitution $$y = \frac{1}{x}$$ and note that $$x\to\infty \implies y\to 0^{+}.$$  This tells us that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x} = \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(1+y\right)^{\frac{1}{y}}.$$  Note now that it doesn't matter what the new variable is called, so we can say $$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is a much more proper and version of something I had thought about previously, this really helps. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1):

If one is allowed to use simple differentiation, in particular the fact that if $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, $x>-1$, then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ then another solution can be obtained as follows:

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=\exp\Big(\tfrac1x\log(1+x)\Big)$$

Notice that $f(0)=\log1=0$ and so
$$\frac1x\log(1+x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0}f'(0)=1$$

Putting things together
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1+x)^{1/x}=\exp(1)=e$$

Comment: A bit of overkill, but +1 for creativity.

Comment: @KamalSaleh: It is not an overkill. It all depends how one gets introduced to the exponential and log functions and $e$. In some modern approaches to Calculus the function $\log x:=\int^x_1\frac1t\,dt$ is define for $x>0$, and from this all properties of the logarithm an exponential functions are deduced. There are also rigorous treatments where the exponential function is define as $\exp(x)=\lim_n(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ and from this all properties of $\exp$ and $\log$ are obtained. In less formal treatments, one tend to learn mechanical tricks without taking proper definitions of certain objects.